# How do we get exact values from the string using C#

Tags: c#

I am using `ContainsAny` to filter the data.
But, when I use this, it will consider all related string.

For example, my string value is `Empcontains` = `"M1"`. It should exactly match only M1 and not others like M2,M3,M4 etc.

```cs
Empcontains = "M1"
ContainsStringExtensions.ContainsAny(r.Field<string>("EMPNO"), Empcontains)
```

How to avoid eliminate other values like contains M2,M3,M4,etc... even "M1" is exists along with the values?
Below is the sample code for understandings.

I have mentioned the complete code is below.
The final output should come EMPTAG = "15" is the output. But, it will come as "40".

What is the problem in the below code.

```cs
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> valcontains = new List<string>() { "MAP" };
    List<string> Empcontains = new List<string>() { "M1" };
    int EmpTagNo = 0;

    DataTable tblData = new DataTable();
    tblData.Columns.Add("EMPNO", typeof(string));
    tblData.Columns.Add("EMPTAG", typeof(int));
    tblData.Columns.Add("EMPDEP", typeof(string));
    tblData.Rows.Add("(MAP) KL+M1+XZ+X1+HM", "15", "CIV");
                        tblData.Rows.Add("(MAP) KL+M1+M3+X1+HM", "20", "MEC");
                        tblData.Rows.Add("(MAP) KL+M1+M5+X1+HM+M7", "40", "IT");
                        tblData.Rows.Add("(MAP) KL+M1+M5+X1+HM+M7", "40", "IT");
                        tblData.Rows.Add("(MAP) KL+M1+M5+X1+HM+M7", "40", "IT");
                        tblData.Rows.Add("(MAP) KL+M1+M5+X1+HM+M7", "40", "IT");
                        tblData.Rows.Add("(MAP) KL+M1+M5+X1+HM+M7", "40", "CIV");

    var Qry = (from r in tblData.AsEnumerable()
               where
               ContainsStringExtensions.ContainsAny(r.Field<string>("EMPNO"), valcontains) &&
               ContainsStringExtensions.ContainsAny(r.Field<string>("EMPNO"), Empcontains)
               select new
               {

               }).Count();
    if (Qry > 0)
    {
        var Qry1 = (from r in tblData.AsEnumerable()
                    where
                    ContainsStringExtensions.ContainsAny(r.Field<string>("EMPNO"), valcontains) &&
                    ContainsStringExtensions.ContainsAny(r.Field<string>("EMPNO"), Empcontains)
                    select new
                    {
                        EMPTAG = r.Field<int>("EMPTAG"),
                    }).Distinct();

        foreach (var n in Qry1)
        {
            EmpTagNo = n.EMPTAG;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class ContainsStringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsAny(this string haystack, IEnumerable<string> filterList)
    {
        //return filterList.Any(haystack.Contains);
        return haystack != null && filterList.Any(haystack.Contains);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear why you expect to end up with "15" instead of "40". The entries with both those EmpTags have M1 in them, and your final loop effectively picks the last matching item from your query. Why should "KL+M1+XZ+X1+HM" match when "KL+M1+M5+X1+HM+M7" shouldn't?

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. I'm Passing passing value Empcontains="M1". the matching record only to be consider where  Empcontains only "M1" along with other values like "KL+M1+XZ+X1+HM" and its EMPTAG is "15". But, the other record also coming "M1" like "KL+M1+M3+X1+HM". But, this will have "M3". So we have to eliminate this record an like others also.  for example,  If i'm passing parameter values   Empcontains="M2"   then we have to consider only M2 records and others should eliminate like "M1","M3" till M8

Comment: In theory, you could use a regular expression to match strings containing "M1" and not containing "M" followed by any other letter or number. But that would give you an EMPTag of "20" because that entry also matches your criteria. Is that okay?

Comment: **Also**, you've added a requirement that the EMPNO value needs to have "MAP" in it. That will *only* match the final entry in your table. What's the purpose and intent of that criteria?

Comment: It looks like you're using a string to represent a complex data model, and then you're trying to filter your items based on an understanding of that more complex data model. I recommend creating C# classes that represent your model, and beginning by parsing your inputs into that model. Then writing a query against that model will be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. i received reference help from JackJJun-MSFT (Microsoft Employee)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/563656/how-do-i-get-exact-match-instead-of-containsany-in.html

```
public static class ContainsStringExtensions
     {
         public static bool ContainsAny(this string haystack, IEnumerable<string> filterList)
         {
             string[] arr = haystack.Replace(filterList.FirstOrDefault(), "").Split('+');
             arr = arr.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
             foreach (var item in arr)
             {
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
                 {
                     if (item.StartsWith(filterList.FirstOrDefault().Substring(0, 1)))
                     {
                         return false;
                     }
                      
                 }
             }
    
             return haystack != null && filterList.Any(haystack.Contains);
    
         }
     }
```

below is the containsany string modified code and it's working fine.